# How to filter data from a file using Python?

Tags: python, filter, parsing

I'm trying to filter certain data from an HTML file. For example, the HTML file is as follows:

```
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]">software_0.1-0.log</td><td align="right">17-Nov-2009 13:46  </td><td align="right">186K</td></tr>
```

I need to extract the software_0.1-0 part as well as the 17-Nov-2009 part. How can I do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: From this example, it's not really clear what the criteria for filtering are - it looks like it might be "text between `<td>` tags", but that doesn't quite fit (there is a `186K` that you don't seem to want). Could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite easy with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
html = '''<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]">software_0.1-0.log</td><td align="right">17-Nov-2009 13:46  </td><td align="right">186K</td></tr>'''

import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.td.next.next
print soup.td.nextSibling.next
```

Output:

```
software_0.1-0.log
17-Nov-2009 13:46
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the strings of interest (and some more text) using for example the popular [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) package.  Then, you'll need some string manipulation (or maybe regular expressions) to separate the exact part of interest, but that depends on exactly what are the rules you want to apply -- i.e., is it always the `.log` suffix you want to drop from the filename, is it always a space that separates the date from the time, and so forth.  If you specify the rules precisely it will not be hard to implement them (without a precise specification, however, it would all be a big mess of guesses;-).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Beautifull Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html), a parser for HTML. You'll get a structured document out of there and could select the first and second td contents.

It may be overkill in this instance, but especially if your HTML is from the outside and can change the maintenance guy will thank you for choosing a readable solution.

Answer (score 0):

you requirement seems simple, so here's the non BeautifulSoup way, just pure string manipulation

```
s="""<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]">software_0.1-0.log</td><td align="right">17-Nov-2009 13:46  </td><td align="right">186K</td></tr>"""

string=s.split(">")
for i in string:
    try:
        e=i.index("<")
    except: pass
    else:
        print i[:e]
```

Now you can use i[:e]  to find "software" and the date part

Comment: While this is technically true, it is still better to use Beautiful Soup because that will pay you dividends in the future when you have to do more complex HTML manipulations.

Comment: until that time when things are more complex, there's no need to use BeautifulSoup just for this case